# adding scroll listener to ContentPanel in gwt

Tags: gwt, gxt

```
((ContentPanel) model1Container.getItems().get(0)).addScrollListener(new ScrollListener() {        
 @Override
            public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {
                super.handleEvent(componentEvent);    
                System>out.println("entered")
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetScrolled(ComponentEvent componentEvent) {
                super.widgetScrolled(componentEvent);

                System.out.println("componentEvent1 = " + componentEvent);
            }
        });
```

Is there any thing wrong with my code? Though I am scrolling but the event is not firing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourPanel.addListener(Events.Scroll, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
    ...
});
```

That, by the way, is how you should be adding all listeners to GXT components. GXT components do not register listeners in the same way that GWT components do. The `ScrollContainer` [docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxtdocs/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/widget/ScrollContainer.html) (of which `ContentPanel` is a child) say that the `Scroll` event is supported, so my example should work unless you have some other issue.

Hope that helps.

-tjw